# How Can I Enter only Numbers and minus sign in this input

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="kinput">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter value" maxlength="7" id="kinput" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
</div>
```

I found this expression

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
```

but it does not let me enter the minus sign. if there is a way  I can include the minus sign without allowing the other non-numeric characters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the `-` as part of the regex (`[^0-9.-]`) to ignore that character in the matching and will skip that in the replace.

```html
<div class="kinput">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter value" maxlength="7" id="kinput" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
</div>
```